# Hide YouTube video embed image before playing

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, youtube-api

I'm making a website and I want to embed a YouTube video. My senior hates the YouTube normal player layout so I'm customizing it a bit (without buttons, etc). The problem is that when I open the site page, YouTube shows a image (player size, in my case 480p) and that image is really destroyed.

I need some way to pick up YouTube embed  code and have a image on top of it. When I click the image, it should change to YouTube  and then automatically start playing the video. This way I can avoid people to see that ugly preview image when they open the page.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you had a look at jQuery's .replaceWith() function?

http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

You could use that to place a div with you image, and when it's clicked replace the content with the Youtube player.

Comment: I don't know much about jQuery. The only thing I got is the embed code I need. Can you write it for me please :x?

Comment: <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="853" height="479.8125"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JUPj5DgPIIk?controls=0&rel=0&showinfo=0"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: Have a look at Pez's answer below. That's pretty much the code version of what I suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youtube won't play a video if it is hidden, so you could try setting auto play to one but having the div hidden and then you could use jQuery to "swap" your cover with the video. The video would load and auto play.

With jQuery:

```
<div id="youtubeplayer" style="display:none;">
<!-- Player code with &autoplay=1 -->
</div>
<div id="coverimageforplayer"><img src="wherever.png" /></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#coverimageforplayer').click(function() {
$('#coverimageforplayer').replaceWith($('#youtubeplayer').show());
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can't get it to work. I've tried to copy the code to my HTML, use the embed <iframe> code inside the <div>, defined a image for the cover, but for much that I click on it, nothing happens.

Comment: For some strange reasons the above mentioned code auto plays even if the user doesn't click on the link. I've found a better solution. Adding it now.

Comment: Here is also a nice solution: http://orangecountycustomwebsitedesign.com/change-the-youtube-embed-image-to-custom-image/

Answer (score 4):

Put a div with an image wherever you want to display the video:

```
<div id="coverimageforplayer"><img class="introvideo" src="video-cover.jpg" width="800" height="450" /></div>
```

Now, add the following jquery code:

```
$('#coverimageforplayer').click(function() {
        var embedCode = '<iframe ...Your Youtube embed code></iframe>';
        $('#coverimageforplayer').html(embedCode);
    });
```

Works like a charm for me.

Comment: Hi, I have used this solution but it's not working on iOS Safari, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

If a high percentage of visitors will never actually initiate playback, I'd recommend going with a method where you just have `img` tags on the page (with whatever custom image you want) until someone clicks on one of them, at which point you swap in the YouTube iframe embedded player. That way you can avoid having to load the player in advance unless you know you actually need it.

There's an example of doing this in the YouTube Direct Lite codebase, including overlaying a "play" icon on the  when you mouse over it. You can see a live demo at

http://ytdirectlite.appspot.com/static-min/submit.html

if you log in to the submission interface at the bottom of that page, then go to the "My YouTube Videos" tab.

There's a few pieces of code that handles that, but the most relevant bits are

https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/source/browse/static/js/ytdl/load.js#71
https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/source/browse/static/js/ytdl/player.js#17